# Исключение в конструкторе С++

Tags: c++

хотел поинтересоваться, считается ли плохим тоном бросать исключение в конструкторе? Я знаю, что объект не будет полностью создан, и из-за этого возможны утечки. Но в моем случае, я использую умные указатели и мне нужно при создании объекта системы проверить его получаемые данные в конструкторе, если что-то не правильно то бросить исключение и уже там сделать exit(), либо может делать exit прямо в конструкторе? Хотелось бы получить подробный ответ на эту тему. За ранее спасибо...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> считается ли плохим тоном бросать исключение в конструкторе?

Нет, не считается. Исключения в том числе для того и предназначены, чтобы предоставить механизм аварийного выхода из тех контекстов, в которых других более-менее элегантных механизмов обработки исключительных ситуаций предложить не получается. Конструкторы как раз относятся к этой категории (операторы - другой пример). Разумеется, бросать исключения надо уметь правильно, чтобы не было никаких утечек.

Однако принятие решения о том, выбросить ли из конструктора исключение или все таки завершить конструирование объекта в некоем "подвешенном" состоянии - вопрос творческий и неоднозначный.

> если что-то не правильно то бросить исключение и уже там сделать exit(), либо может делать exit прямо в конструкторе

У вас какая-то безусловная завязанность на `exit` наблюдается. Бросание и обработка исключений совсем не предполагает обязательного завершения программы. Исключение можно поймать, обработать, восстановиться после него и продолжить нормальную работу.

Но если в вашем случае возникновение исключительной ситуации обязательно приводит к завершению работы всей программы, то зашивать безусловное убивание всей программы в конструктор какого-то объекта - в большинстве случаев дурной тон. Лучше все таки просто выбросить исключение, а решение о завершении принять на более высоком уровне.

Comment: чтобы завершить программу, достаточно просто не обработать исключение

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Да, достаточно. Но, во-первых, не всем нравится как выглядит такое "бесконтрольное" завершение. Во-вторых, язык не гарантирует раскрутку стека, если исключение не обработано, т.е. освобождение потенциально имеющихся захваченных ресурсов может оказаться кривым или не произойти вообще.

Comment: хотите сказать что  после вызова  terminate()  может не произойти раскрутка стека? .  Я не уверен...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Об этом отрытым текстом сказано в стандарте. (См. также https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887319/why-is-stack-unwinding-guaranteed-only-for-handled-exceptions). Раскрутка стека для необработанного исключения *не гарантируется* (решение принимается реализацией). Сделано так для того, чтобы система в такой ситуации уже после падения программы могла сформировать полноценный coredump по еще не раскрученному стеку.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Вам я верю, поскольку в таких вопросах вы спец.  Изучу тему подробнее